# What is the optimal $k$ for the $k$ nearest neighbour classifier on the Iris dataset?

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour

What is the optimal value of $k$, for an unweighted Euclidean  kNN classifier applied to the [Iris data set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set)?

Where optimal implies the value for $k$ which leads to the lowest generalisation error.

Comment: Define "optimal"

Comment: I know what classification error rates are and I know you can look to find the classifier with the lowest estimate average error rate but what does generalisation error mean?

Comment: @image_doctor you also need to explain how you are going to estimate the generalization error... is it the error on a separate test set or with cross-validation?

Comment: @MichaelChernick In this context generalisation error is the term for the average error on unseen data. It is often estimated by some derived metric on test data. Such as n-Fold CV, 50/50 Holdout  or Bootstrapping.

Comment: That then is what I would call average of the class conditional error rates. In a two class problem there are two error rates. So you would try to minimize a weighted average of the two. often the weighting could be equal but not always because sometimes the consequences of making one type error can be a lot greater than the for making the other.  For the Iris dat you have three classes and equal weighting would probably make sense.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I'm not aware of any standard cost function for the Iris dataset, so the they would seem to be broadly equivalent definitions.

Comment: Yes i would expect equal weighting would be appropriate for the iris data.

Comment: @Pardis I was reluctant to specify a specific method for generalisation error, as whilst it gives repeatability I felt that there might be some interesting variation in the results from different metrics. But so far there is a lack of diversity in approaches :)

Comment: @MichaelChernick What do you think is the best value for K in the case of the Iris data?

Comment: @image_doctor again, this all depends on your definition of "best," which depends both on the metric you wish to minimize (or maximize) and the method you choose to calculate that error (n-fold cv, leave-one-out-cv, etc.). The answer I posted will allow you to try any metric you can think of and a variety of re-sampling methods.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Lets say you want to use Accuracy (or % correct) to evaluate "optimal," and you have time to look at 25 values for k.  The following R code will answer your question using 15 repeats of 10-fold cross-validation.  It will also take a long time to run.

```
library(caret)
model <- train(
    Species~., 
    data=iris, 
    method='knn',
    tuneGrid=expand.grid(.k=1:25),
    metric='Accuracy',
    trControl=trainControl(
        method='repeatedcv', 
        number=10, 
        repeats=15))

model
plot(model)
> confusionMatrix(model)
Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 15 times) Confusion Matrix 

(entries are percentages of table totals)

            Reference
Prediction   setosa versicolor virginica
  setosa       33.3        0.0       0.0
  versicolor    0.0       31.9       1.2
  virginica     0.0        1.4      32.1
```

[image: Accuracy]

So, by this criteria, I get an answer of 17, but it looks like the "true" value could lie anywhere between 5 and 20.  You can substitute "Kappa" or some other metric if you want, and add more cv-folds as well.  You can also try different methods of cross validation, such as leave-one-out, or bootstrap re-sampling.

/Edit: in response for your request for variety, I wrote this function to calculate a variety of metrics for multi-class problems:

```
#Multi-Class Summary Function
#Based on caret:::twoClassSummary
require(compiler)
multiClassSummary <- cmpfun(function (data, lev = NULL, model = NULL){

  #Load Libraries
  require(Metrics)
  require(caret)

  #Check data
  if (!all(levels(data[, "pred"]) == levels(data[, "obs"]))) 
    stop("levels of observed and predicted data do not match")

  #Calculate custom one-vs-all stats for each class
  prob_stats <- lapply(levels(data[, "pred"]), function(class){

    #Grab one-vs-all data for the class
    pred <- ifelse(data[, "pred"] == class, 1, 0)
    obs  <- ifelse(data[,  "obs"] == class, 1, 0)
    prob <- data[,class]

    #Calculate one-vs-all AUC and logLoss and return
    cap_prob <- pmin(pmax(prob, .000001), .999999)
    prob_stats <- c(auc(obs, prob), logLoss(obs, cap_prob))
    names(prob_stats) <- c('ROC', 'logLoss')
    return(prob_stats) 
  })
  prob_stats <- do.call(rbind, prob_stats)
  rownames(prob_stats) <- paste('Class:', levels(data[, "pred"]))

  #Calculate confusion matrix-based statistics
  CM <- confusionMatrix(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"])

  #Aggregate and average class-wise stats
  #Todo: add weights
  class_stats <- cbind(CM$byClass, prob_stats)
  class_stats <- colMeans(class_stats)

  #Aggregate overall stats
  overall_stats <- c(CM$overall)

  #Combine overall with class-wise stats and remove some stats we don't want 
  stats <- c(overall_stats, class_stats)
  stats <- stats[! names(stats) %in% c('AccuracyNull', 'Prevalence', 'Detection Prevalence')]

  #Clean names and return
  names(stats) <- gsub('[[:blank:]]+', '_', names(stats))
  return(stats)
})
```

It's a doozy of a function, so it's going to slow down caret a bit, but I'd be very happy if you posted the results of your 1000 repeats of 10-fold CV (I have neither the time not the computational capacity to attempt this at present).  Here's my code for 15 repeats of 10-fold CV.  Note that you can easily modify this code to try other re-sampling methods, such as bootstrap sampling:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(19556)
model <- train(
  Species~., 
  data=iris, 
  method='knn',
  tuneGrid=expand.grid(.k=1:30),
  metric='Accuracy',
  trControl=trainControl(
    method='repeatedcv', 
    number=10, 
    repeats=15,
    classProbs=TRUE,
    summaryFunction=multiClassSummary))
```

Both [ROC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_under_curve) and LogLoss seem to peak around 8:
[image: ROC]
[image: logLoss]

While [sensitivity and specificity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specificity_%28statistics%29) seem to peak around 15:
[image: Sens] 
[image: Spec]

Here's some code to output all the plots as a pdf:

```
dev.off()
pdf('plots.pdf')
for(stat in c('Accuracy', 'Kappa', 'AccuracyLower', 'AccuracyUpper', 'AccuracyPValue', 
              'Sensitivity', 'Specificity', 'Pos_Pred_Value', 
              'Neg_Pred_Value', 'Detection_Rate', 'ROC', 'logLoss')) {

  print(plot(model, metric=stat))
}
dev.off()
```

If you put a gun to my head, I'd probably say 8...

Comment: Thanks very much for that, I ran your code with 1,000 repetitions. The most interesting values seemed to be 14 and 17.

Comment: @image_doctor: you should also try with "method=boot632" and  "method=boot", with a high number of repetitions, and see what number those two methods pick.  Also, if my answer is sufficient, feel free to make it as "accepted."

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and your excellent answer. I was hoping to get a diversity of answers in an attempt to draw some a more general conclusions. A sample of one, doesn't leave much space for any variance calculations ;) If no new answers appear after some time, I will very happily make yours the accepted answer.

Comment: @image_doctor: You can use the code I posted to get a variety of answers.  Try setting the metric to 'Kappa' rather than 'Accuracy' and see what you get for an answer.  Then try both metrics, with the train control method set to 'boot', then 'boot632,' 'LOOCV,' and 'LGOCV.'  That will get you to a sample size of 10.  Next, you can write a custom `summaryFunction,` perhaps starting with the average of AUC, Sensitivity, Specificity, Precision, and Recall for each of the three classes.  That will get you to a sample size of 35...

Comment: I don't really see a whole lot to add to his answer.  Cross-Validation or Bootstrapping are by far the most appropriate ways to understand this.  You limited us to Euclidean distance.  He appropriately retained uncertainty in his answer (5-20).  He chose a common error metric (I'd have chose multivariate log-loss, but it's not available by default in caret).  And he introduced an appropriate tool: `caret` in R.

Comment: @image_doctor: You mention 14 and 17, but my feeling is that those two particular numbers wouldn't be superior if you actually went out and gathered some more iris data. My guess would be that the broad 5..20 peak is what it is, and the peaks and valleys in that range are artifacts of the Iris dataset, not of irises.

Comment: In the first step, where you selected 25 for the max k-nearest, was that an arbitrary decision or it based on some "good practice"?